# Configuring some routes on some PCs

Tags: ping

A lot simplier question related to my first question here:

[image]

This is a network set up.

1 router, 1 switch, 4 PCs (with several NICs)

A can ping B and C (reverse also true)
C can ping A, B, and D (reverse also true)

How do I configure so that A and B can ping D and D can ping A and B? I cannot change any IP and not touching the router.

My logical idea would be to set up a route. How do I do this on A and B?

Thank you

Comment: What is the connection between `C` and `D`? Is that direct NIC to NIC connection? Does 172.16.0.0/16 network exist anywhere else except between `C` and `D`? What's the purpose of 10.10.10.0/24 on `A` and `B`?

Comment: Can `C` be used to route traffic or is it just regular PC or server?

Comment: You say you *"cannot change any IP and not touching the router."* yet you say *"My logical idea would be to set up a route"*. Do you mean you can change the routes on the PCs but not on the router?

Comment: Yes, the connection between C and D is a direct NIC to NIC connection. 172.6.9.0 does not exist anywhere else except in C and D. The question isn't really related about having purpose (I do not mean that in a rude way). C cannot be used to route traffic, A can. And yes; I can only change routes on the PCs, not the router.

Comment: If C cannot route traffic, then there is no way to get the traffic from D to A/B since the traffic would have to *go through* C (which again cannot route the traffic). Routes modified on any workstation just affect how it routes it's traffic and it will drop any traffic not intended for it (i.e. it will only allow unicast traffic destined to it, broadcast traffic or relevant multicast).

Comment: I though it was possible for C to route thru A and therefore D would be visible. I apologize for my error. Lets use as you mentioned C for routing. My mistake for not understanding the problem at hand.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that follows is assuming a traditional, classroom networking environment.

Right now, D is not connected to any device that will allow it access to a network. It is connected to another client (C), establishing an ad-hoc point to point network connection.

Based on the information provided, the only way to solve is to add a physical connection from D to the switch.

The main question that I would ask is: How are each of the clients A, B, and C capable of multiple IP addresses, when the diagram clearly only shows a single physical connection? Where a switch/router would be able to apply IP interfaces onto VLANs, a PC is not capable of doing so. Is there a communication media that we are unaware of (wireless)?

Comment: They are assigned by static.